Flutter mac OS build failed
I am getting an error when running the flutter macOS app on my M1 machine.
It was running perfectly last day but is showing an error now. It was working perfectly on the iPhone.
My pubspec.yaml
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.8
  firebase_core: ^3.9.0
  cloud_firestore: ^5.6.0
  flutter_bloc: ^8.1.3
  bloc: ^8.1.3
  firebase_auth: ^5.3.4
  equatable: ^2.0.7
  crypto: ^3.0.6

Error
[        ] ** BUILD FAILED **
[        ] The following build commands failed:
[        ]  SwiftEmitModule normal arm64 Emitting\ module\ for\ FirebaseSharedSwift (in target 'FirebaseSharedSwift' from project 'Pods')
[        ]  EmitSwiftModule normal arm64 (in target 'FirebaseSharedSwift' from project 'Pods')
[        ]  SwiftEmitModule normal arm64 Emitting\ module\ for\ FirebaseCoreInternal (in target 'FirebaseCoreInternal' from project 'Pods')
[        ]  EmitSwiftModule normal arm64 (in target 'FirebaseCoreInternal' from project 'Pods')
[   +1 ms]  Building workspace Runner with scheme Runner and configuration Debug
[        ] (5 failures)
[  +79 ms] Error: Build process failed
[   +2 ms] 
           #0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:10:3)
           #1      RunCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart:790:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #2      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1408:27)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #3      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:153:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #4      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:212:13)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #5      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:420:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #6      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:153:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #7      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:364:5)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #8      run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:130:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #9      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:153:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #10     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:93:3)
           <asynchronous suspension>


The error Command SwiftEmitModule failed typically occurs when there is an issue with the Swift code in your Flutter project, often related to dependencies or the Swift version compatibility.
Some steps to troubleshoot and resolve your issue:


flutter pub get
flutter clean
cd ios
rm -rf Pods Podfile.lock
pod install



If the steps above not working, you can try again with the following steps (Noted: I faced when upgrade my application to the newest stable flutter version: flutter 3.27.1 & Dart 3.6.0)

-rf <path to flutter repo>/bin/cache
flutter doctor -v
flutter clean
flutter pub get
cd in ios directory in the project and pod install, then run pod update
Finally, flutter run

